# Преобразование TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE в Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone

По каким-то причинам не получается правильно преобразовать `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` из одной временной зоны в другую, пример:

```
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP,
       DBTIMEZONE,
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
       SESSIONTIMEZONE
  FROM DUAL;
```

---

```
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================
|                   SYSTIMESTAMP                   |                    DBTIMEZONE                    |                CURRENT_TIMESTAMP                 |                 SESSIONTIMEZONE                  |
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================
|            20.07.2017 7:15:33 -04:00             |                  Europe/Moscow                   |            20.07.2017 14:15:33 +03:00            |                      +03:00                      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Второй пример:

```
SELECT 
  SYSTIMESTAMP,
  SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Moscow' Moscow,
  SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' New_York
  FROM DUAL
```

---

```
==========================================================================================================================================================
|                   SYSTIMESTAMP                   |                      MOSCOW                      |                     NEW_YORK                     |
==========================================================================================================================================================
|            20.07.2017 7:09:25 -04:00             |            20.07.2017 11:09:25 +00:00            |            20.07.2017 11:09:25 +00:00            |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

В данном случае в результате преобразования часовой пояс вообще сбросился, не смотря на успешное выполнение преобразования.

1. Почему в первом примере результат `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` отстает на час от реального, которое должно быть равно `15:15:33`, а не `14:15:33`?
2. Почему во втором примере, не смотря на успешное выполнение команды, конвертация не происходит? Может какие-то параметры базы данных не настроены, или я не понимаю как `AT TIME ZONE` работает? Наименования временных зон я брал из `V$TIMEZONE_NAMES`.

Версия БД: Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

**UPD:**
Данные из `nls_session_parameters`

SQL Developer

```
NLS_LANGUAGE    RUSSIAN
NLS_TERRITORY   RUSSIA
NLS_CURRENCY    ₽
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    RUSSIA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  , 
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD.MM.RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   RUSSIAN
NLS_SORT    RUSSIAN
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH24:MI:SSXFF
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   ₽
NLS_COMP    BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
```

dbForge

```
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY    $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
NLS_SORT    BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   $
NLS_COMP    BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    CHAR
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
```

Comment: Уточните, в первом примере - SYSTIMESTAMP показывает время по-NY, -4 и +3 = 7 часов разницы, вроде правильно, но вы не жалуетесь, что в Нью Йорке часы тоже отстают.

Comment: @0xdb, я на это не обратил внимание, если честно, получается оно на час в принципе отстает

Comment: Ну тогда с 1-м вопросом понятно,  системноое время установлено не верно. Ко 2-му вопросу: Преобразование производит клиент. Каким вы пользуетесь? Какие NLS настройки, переменные окружения, что возвращает nls_session_parameters? Можете попробовать sqlpus прямо на машине, где база установлена?

Comment: @0xdb 1 действительно вылечилось установкой системного времени. Со вторым получилось, что SQL Developer производит правильно преобразования, а dbForge\плагин к IDEA нет. Думаю, можете написать это как ответ и я его приму тогда. Параметры сессии тоже скинул в вопрос.

Comment: Рад, что получилось. Напишу ответ вечером. В вопросе, как я понял - dbForge.  SQL Developer тоже не безгрешен, а sqlpus пока замечен не был.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**К 1-ой части вопроса**

`SYSTIMESTAMP` возвращает текущее время и часовой пояс операционной системы машины на которой установлен сервер БД.

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` возвращает эти же данные учитывая часовой пояс сессии на клиенте, который определяется клиентом из окружения (установки региона на ОС, переменные) в котором он запущен и может быть изменён непосредственно: `setenv ORA_SDTZ="Europe/Moscow"` или `alter session set time_zone='+03:00'`.

Посмотреть часовой пояс сессии можно так:

```
select sessiontimezone from dual;
```

В примере разница между Москвой и Нью-Йорком составляет -4 и +3 = 7 часов, что соответствует действительности. Значит время, которое возвращает `SYSTIMESTAMP` тоже с отставанием, т.е. системное время установленно не верно.

**Ко 2-ой части вопроса**

Преобразование даты и времени производится на стороне клиента и зависит от его NLS настроек, часового пояса (см. выше), которые можно посмотреть:

```
select * from nls_session_parameters;
```

Некоторые клиенты, как в данном примере с `dbForge\IDEA` "потерялся" часовой пояс, или `sqlplus` не учитывает изменения часового пояса в России с октября 2014 года,   выполняют преобразование не всегда верно. Поэтому при сомнении имеет смысл выполнить запрос на различных клиентах.

**На заметку не в рамках вопроса**

*Oracle* рекомендует устанавливать `DBTIMEZONE` на UTC, если не используются по каким-то специфическим соображениям тип данных `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`.